# Property from PropertySource is not used

Tags: java, spring

I've got a question for programmatically added properties to a spring context.

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ConfigurableEnvironment ctxEnvironment = ctx.getEnvironment();
ctxEnvironment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("rootProperties", new FileSystemResource("/tmp/root.properties")));
ctx.load(new ClassPathResource("/context/application-context.xml"));
ctx.refresh();
```

root.properties:

```
test=hello
```

Snippet from application context:

```
...
<property name="test" value="${test} world"/>
...
```

When I load the bean from the context, ${test} is not substituted with "hello".

Spring version: 5.1.5.RELEASE

What am I missing here?

PS: Btw, this works:

```
 System.out.println("Text: " + ctxEnvironment.resolvePlaceholders("${test}"));
```

Output:

```
 Text: hello
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add: I don't want to use the `context:property-placeholder` bean, because I know the location of the properties file only at runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure but just want to give a try `<property name="test" value="${test}"+"world"/>` like this

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to only use the property name in the value attribute. Didn't help.

Comment: please share the startup logs of your application

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your case and it's working for me. You need to add a property place holder in your applicationContext.xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:/tmp/root.properties" />
    <bean id="myA" class="com.zpavel.MyA">
        <property name="test" value="${test}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

For example a simple bean :

```
public class MyA {

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

You can load it with :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/context/application-context.xml");
MyA myA = context.getBean(MyA.class);
System.out.println(myA.getTest());
```

It will print "hello" as expected.

Comment: I don't want to use the `context:property-placeholder` bean, because I know the location of the properties file only at runtime.

Comment: You can set the location of your file at runtime by -Dmyfile=/tmp/root.properties and then property placeholder becomes <context:property-placeholder location="file:${myfile}" />

Comment: Thanks, that actually works, but I still need the `context:property`. I also want to use the properties only if available, so that would still be a little problem. Ccould use a placeholder, I know - but I found a pure programmatic approach right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

I have tested with this.

**applicationContext.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="application.properties" />
    <bean id="demo"
        class="com.example.Demo">
        <property name="value1" value="${test} world" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**application.properties :**

```
test = Hello
```

**Demo.java** :

```
public class Demo {

    String value1;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value1;
    }

}
```

**Test.java :**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "applicationContext.xml");
        Demo demo = (Demo) classPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean("demo");
        System.out.println(demo);
        classPathXmlApplicationContext.close();
    }

}
```

**When you run, the output :**

```
Hello world
```

**The problem is with the bean. Please check it.**

Comment: I don't want to use the `context:property-placeholder` bean, because I know the location of the properties file only at runtime.

Comment: Ok that's fine. But I want to say that it's working fine. Some other issue may be there. Check for that

Answer (score 0):

After some more diving into the spring API I found a pure programmatic solution to my problem without the need of a `context:property` element. For anyone interested, here is the full source:

**Test.java**

```
  public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();

          PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
          MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
          propertySources.addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("rootProperties", new ClassPathResource("/root.properties")));
          configurer.setPropertySources(propertySources);
          ctx.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);

          ctx.load(new ClassPathResource("/ctx.xml"));
          ctx.refresh();

          TestBean bean = ctx.getBean(TestBean.class);
          System.out.println(bean.getString());
      }
  }
```

**TestBean.java**

```
  public class TestBean {
      String string = "";

      public String getString() { return string; }
      public void setString(String string) { this.string = string; }
  }
```

**ctx.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd">
      <beans>
          <bean class="TestBean">
              <property name="string" value="${test} world"/>
          </bean>
      </beans>
  </beans>
```

**root.properties**

```
  test=hello
```